# LL(1) cannot be ambiguous

Tags: compiler-construction, grammar

How can it be shown that no LL(1) grammar can be ambiguous?

I know what is ambiguous grammar but could not prove the above theorem/lemma.

Comment: There can be no such proof, since freedom from ambiguity is part of the DEFINITION of LL(k) grammars. You cannot prove a definition. A simple example is A: a|a. Given input "a", there are exactly two parses that recognize or accept the "a", so this grammar is not LL(1) because it is ambiguous. Note that A has a valid FIRST set: {a}.

Answer (score 9):

Here's my first draft at a proof.  It might need some fine tuning, but I think it covers all the cases.  I think many solutions are possible.  This is a direct proof.

(Side note: it is a pity SO doesn't support math, such as in LaTeX.)

**Proof**

Let T and N be the sets of terminal and non-terminal symbols.

Let the following hold

```
MaybeEmpty(s) = true <=> s ->* empty
First(s) = X containing all x for which there exists Y such that s ->* xY
Follow(A) = X containing all x for which there exists Y,Z such that S ->* YAxZ
```

Note that a grammar is LL(1) if the following holds for every pair of productions A -> B and A -> C:

```
1. (not MaybeEmpty(B)) or (not MaybeEmpty(C))
2. (First(B) intersect First(C)) = empty
3. MaybeEmpty(C) => (First(B) intersect Follow(A)) = empty
```

Consider a language with is LL(1), with `A -> B` and `A -> C`.
That is to say there is some string of terminals TZ which admits multiple derivations by distinct parse trees.

Suppose that the left derivation reaches `S ->* TAY ->* TZ`.  The next step may be either `TAY -> TBY`, or `TAY -> TCY`.
Thus the language is ambiguous if both `BY ->* Z` and `CY ->* Z`.
(Note that since A is an arbitrary non-terminal, if no such case exists, the language is non-ambiguous.)

Case 1: Z = empty

By rule 1 of LL(1) grammars, at most one of B and C can derive empty (non-ambiguous case).

Case 2: Z non-empty, and neither B nor C derive empty

By rule 2 of LL(1) grammars, at most one of B and C can permit further derivation because the leading terminal of Z cannot be in both `First(B)` and `First(C)` (non-ambiguous case).

Case 3: Z non-empty, and either `MaybeEmpty(B)` or `MaybeEmpty(C)`

Note the by rule 1 of LL(1) grammars, B and C cannot both derive empty.  Suppose therefore that `MaybeEmpty(C)` is true.

This gives two sub-cases.

Case 3a: `CY -> Y`; and Case 3b: `CY ->* DY`, where D is not empty.

In 3a we must choose between `BY ->* Z` and `CY -> Y ->* Z`, but notice that `First(Y) subset-of Follow(A)`.  Since `Follow(A)` does not intersect `First(B)`, only one derivation can proceed (non-ambiguous).

In 3b we must choose between `BY ->* Z` and `CY ->* DY ->* Z`, but notice that `First(D) subset-of First(C)`.  Since `First(C)` does not intersect `First(B)`, only one derivation can proceed (non-ambiguous).

Thus in every case the derivation can only be expanded by one of the available productions.  Therefore the grammar is not ambiguous.

Comment: You cannot prove a definition. See my comment above.

Comment: @DavidSpector There are many grammars which are non-ambiguous but still not LL(k). Some of these are LR(k) which contains LL(k).

For interest, you may be surprised to find that the exclusion of ambiguity does not feature in any standard definition of LL(k) grammars, although that idea is often expressed informally.

One reason this may surprise is that people often learn LL(k) parsing, which is predictive and deterministic. LL(k) grammars look at the same stuff from the other side. They are generative not predictive, and there is no concept of determinism in formal grammars.

Comment: I'm not following you. Did you really mean to write what you did? It is easy to write a grammar like A -> b; A -> b that appears to be LL(1) because it looks like it has clear FIRST sets, but because they overlap, the grammar is ambiguous. Such grammars are not LL(k) because ambiguity makes them not LL(k); there is no other reason.

Comment: @DavidSpector Yes. Let's explore your example. A simple parser might treat A -> b; A -> b; as two productions. This grammar seems ambiguous, but it is not, as the [productions of a grammar are actually a set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_and_nonterminal_symbols#Production_rules), so duplicates unify. This grammar is actually the same as A->b. Getting back to the definition of LL(k), it doesn't mention ambiguity exclusion because, although necessary, it isn't sufficient, and can be derived mathematically other properties. That's what was shown here for LL(1).

Comment: Thank you for your correction, but I still have a doubt. Ambiguity means there are two possible parses (paths through the productions) for some input. While it is true that grammars are described using sets, two identical productions are represented by two different sets, having the same content. Thus for input b there are two parses, one choosing the first production and one choosing the second. LL(k) grammar theory, I think, does not explicitly provide a way to merge productions with identical content.

Comment: Also, here is an ambiguous grammar that works similarly, but has no duplicate productions: S: 'a' A | B 'a'
A: 'a'
B: 'a'.  The input is "aa".

Comment: @DavidSpector I like your example as it shows a common prefix can be hidden by nesting. This grammar is definitely ambiguous, as 'aa' can be derived in two ways. I think we agree that it is also not LL(k) for any k. Our question is then whether it is not LL(k) because ambiguous grammars are excluded by definition, or whether it is not LL(k) because some other condition is violated. Here for k=1 we have First('a' A) = 'a' and First(B 'a') = 'a', which have a non-empty intersection. So by definition the grammar is not LL(1). However, these low-level conditions do also exclude ambiguity.

Comment: I think you have reached the pivotal conclusion on which we agree: that a nonempty intersection between the FIRST sets for two productions having the same LHS nonterminal symbol is indeed the only way that an LL(1) parse can have more than one distinct parse tree, which is the definition of an ambiguous grammar. So whether the ambiguity is caused by duplicate productions (my first example) or a nested common prefix (my second example), an LL(1) grammar cannot be ambiguous. Contrary to your original comment, LL(1) grammars are predictive and deterministic (unlike general context-free grammars).

Comment: @DavidSpector I see my very first response caused some confusion. To be clear, LL(k) grammars are _deterministic_ context-free grammars  (adjective), and I did not mean otherwise. Rather I was saying that _determinism_ (noun) is not a distinct concept with grammars, but only features in how grammars relate to the computing machinery of parsers, or at least recognisers, both usually deterministic. Let's leave that topic aside, as it is not essential to our main subject.

Comment: @DavidSpector I really believe that we are on the same side of this discussion. You have laid out sound intuition that LL(1) grammars cannot be ambiguous, and the proof here expresses the same idea formally.

Comment: I'm actually creating an LL(k) parser system currently, and I'm finding that simple intuitive grammars can be ambiguous. I'm also realizing that ambiguity in parsing is not really harmful, if your semantic actions are done bottom-up. I'm also realizing that achieving LR(k) can be done with rather inexpensive local backtracking. Learning a lot of practical stuff by doing. These insights are not in books. I like FIRST hinting just as an optimization for more general CFG parsing. The more general the grammar, the easier it is to write down!

Answer (score 8):

I think it's nearly a direct result of the definition of LL(1). Try proof by contradiction; assume that you have an LL(1) grammar that is ambiguous and look for something you can show to be true and not true. As a starting point "what do you always know as you process input?"

As this seems like a homework problem and I actually haven't finished the problem any more than I sketched out above, I'll stop there.

Comment: BTW, I'm not *sure the conjecture is correct, but it does seem reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

Prove that no ambiguous grammar can be an LL(1) grammar.  For hints, see http://www.cse.ohio-state.edu/~rountev/756/pdf/SyntaxAnalysis.pdf, slides 18-20.  Also see http://seclab.cs.sunysb.edu/sekar/cse304/Parse.pdf, pg. 11 and preceding.